# sinon mocking timeouts in a webpack build gets error - 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'modules[moduleId].call'

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon, stubbing

Using webpack to build, and using sinon to mock a timeout, I am getting this error.

undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'modules[moduleId].call

The code is given below.

```
var sinon = require('sinon');

describe('sinon stubbing', function () {
var clock;

before(function () {
    clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();
});

it('should wait for timeout and test', function (done) {
    //code with window.timeout testing 
    clock.tick(1000);
    done();
});

after(function () {
    clock.restore();
});
```

});

Ive used

```
  npm install --save-dev mocha chai sinon
```

to install dependencies. I've tried to manually add sinon version to package.json as well, but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with my package.json.
I need to specify sinon dependency like this.

```
  "sinon": "git+https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon.git"
```

This issue has been reported  [here](https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/issues/830)